# The type serialized in the .resources file was not the same type that the .resources file said it contained

Tags: listview, .net-4.0, badimageformatexception

We have upgraded a large project from .NET 3.5 to .NET 4.0. Everything work fine except the error regarding loading resources from ListView. Now we are just before release and this is a very blocker.

It is a known issue by Microsoft, for example [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2538717) or [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/49ace5c9-ad22-4f08-9b0c-f9c01649cf6f/designer-crashes-when-usercontrol-contains-treeview). There is a [hotfix](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2538717) for this issue, but we tried all available service pack for .NET Framework 4.0, but nothing worked.

We tried to install: KB2416472, KB2487367, KB2604121, KB2729449, KB2736428,
KB2737019, KB2742595, KB2840628, KB2858302v2, KB2861188, KB2972106, KB2972215, 
KB2978125, KB2979575v2, KB3023221, KB3032662, KB3037578, KB3048074, KB3072309, KB3074547 - but without success.

The fix should be in CLR in 4.0.30319.461 (GDR).

I also tried to change a designer bit, to force Visual Studio to change it to .NET 4 format. It does not help.

The only way how to solved this issue was to install .NET Framework 4.5.2. But we don't want to drop support of Windows XP.

Another solution is to switch *Localizable* property to false for all such user controls. It seems a lot of work to me and we want to keep localization. And it is enough? We are not able test all controls and scenarios just before release in reasonable time.

Is there some real solution? Is there some service pack available?

I don't want to believe that .NET Framework 4.0 is not stable. This Winform control is a basic feature in .NET!

```
CLR Excepton: System.BadImageFormatException: The type serialized in the .resources file was not the same type that the .resources file said it contained. Expected 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem' but read 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem+ListViewSubItem'.
   at System.Resources.ResourceReader.TypeLimitingDeserializationBinder.BindToType(String assemblyName, String typeName)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Bind(String assemblyString, String typeString)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.GetType(BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, String name)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectMap..ctor(String objectName, String[] memberNames, BinaryTypeEnum[] binaryTypeEnumA, Object[] typeInformationA, Int32[] memberAssemIds, ObjectReader objectReader, Int32 objectId, BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, SizedArray assemIdToAssemblyTable)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadObjectWithMapTyped(BinaryObjectWithMapTyped record)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadObjectWithMapTyped(BinaryHeaderEnum binaryHeaderEnum)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Resources.ResourceReader.DeserializeObject(Int32 typeIndex)
   at System.Resources.ResourceReader._LoadObjectV2(Int32 pos, ResourceTypeCode& typeCode)
   at System.Resources.ResourceReader.LoadObjectV2(Int32 pos, ResourceTypeCode& typeCode)
   at System.Resources.ResourceReader.LoadObject(Int32 pos)
   at System.Resources.ResourceReader.ResourceEnumerator.get_Entry()
   at System.Resources.ResourceReader.ResourceEnumerator.get_Current()
   at System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager.FillResources(CultureInfo culture, ResourceSet& resourceSet)
   at System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager.FillResources(CultureInfo culture, ResourceSet& resourceSet)
   at System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager.ApplyResources(Object value, String objectName, CultureInfo culture)
```

Comment: It is a very obscure problem.  The odds that the hotfix can still work are zilch, .NET 4.0 has been updated many times since then.  Also very, very strange that they did this with a CLR patch, makes no sense.  Pretty unlikely you'll get help here when you can't demonstrate the issue, the call stack doesn't cut it.  Still wanting to support XP costs money, spend on a phone call to Microsoft Support.  Although they probably tell you to intentionally install an old revision of .NET so the hotfix can still work. Don't make that your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can run .NET 4.5 on WinXP if you have Service Pack 3 installed - 
two problems there are its not officially supported and your app may be buggy 
(not to mention SP3 it self de-stabilizes systems) 
But you can say your app has support for Windows XP

Now from what I know and what I have read there is no real fix for this under your criteria (XP support, setting localizable to true)

My suggestion drop support for the obsolete operating system.

I ran into a similar issue where I developed an app in .NET 4.5 and to build the app with XP support I made a copy of the project and built it with .NET 3.5.

Sorry I can't really help with what you want
but maybe this info will help you!

Cheers,
Demetry